# Ruby's respond_to? method is not working - method exists but false is returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9.3 and ThinkingSphinx (latest version).

This code worked Ok on Ruby 1.8.7 / Rails 2.3 but does not work since I have upgraded to the above.

```
ads = Ad.search "ipod"

ads.respond_to?(:total_entries)

puts ads.total_entries #outputs 472
```

Specifically

> ads.respond_to?(:total_entries)

returns false, however when I invoke this method on the ads object it works ok / as expected.

Can anyone see what is going on here?

Comment: Depends. Is the method dynamically created? Does respond_to work after you've called it the first time?

Answer (score 2):

This could be dynamic method or a ghost method
if

```
ads.respond_to?(:total_entries) # => false
ads.total_entries
ads.respond_to?(:total_entries) # => true
```

that means in somewhere(maybe in `method_missing`) the `total_entries` has been created dynamically like:

```
define_method :total_entries do 
  #do some stuff here
end
```

or if

```
ads.respond_to?(:total_entries) # => false
ads.total_entries
ads.respond_to?(:total_entries) # => false
```

then `method_missing` just handled it with the method name as a parameter and did what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Even if `ads.total_entries` works that does not necessary mean that puts `total_entries` method exists.

When you call a non-existing method, Ruby invokes `method_missing` handler that may handle your call.

To find the exact reason, please provide the definition of the class that `Ad.search` returns.

Comment: The class is ThinkingSphinx::Search but the method is in this file (part of TS): https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/blob/master/lib/thinking_sphinx/masks/pagination_mask.rb

Comment: This class has `total_entries()` method. Not sure why `respond_to?` returns `false`.